# Modify Accumulo Column Qualifier

Tags: accumulo

I am new to accumulo and I have inherited of a bug where a process failed to populate the column qualifier for a specific column family (CF = eLoaderFlag):

```
root@cluster> scan -t adminTable
20160826 dayFlag:e_scope [system.visibility]
922337 eLoaderFlag: [system.visibility]  <-------------------- Entry without CQ, CF = eLoaderFlag
raw_e_scope iAddedLoaderFlag:raw_e_scope [system.visibility]
```

I fixed the process so that any future row with CF = eLoaderFlag will have a CQ:

```
root@cluster> scan -t adminTable
20160826 dayFlag:e_scope [system.visibility]
922337 eLoaderFlag:e_scope [system.visibility]  <------------- CQ = e_scope, CF = eLoaderFlag
raw_e_scope iAddedLoaderFlag:raw_e_scope [system.visibility]
```

But now, I need to update all the records previously inserted which do not have a CQ for this specific CF. Is there a way to update the CQ given the CF ? The Accumulo shell doc does not seem to cover this scenario.

Comment: You'll most likely have to write a program to do this.

Answer (score 1):

@FuriousGeorge is right here.

Key-Value pairs are immutable in Accumulo. You would need to delete the old Key-Value pair and insert a new one.